# HTML input affecting entire page

Tags: jquery, html

I am making a page where you can enter HTML and see the output in a div to the side.
Code:

```js
$("#tryit").keyup(function() {
  var input = $(this).val();
  $("#readout").html(input);
});
```

```css
#readout {
  height: 400px;
  width: 48%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow: auto;
  float: right;
  clear: none;
  display: inline-block;
}
#tryit {
  height: 396px;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  clear: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: monospace;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea name="tryit" id="tryit" rows="10">&lt;!doctype html&gt; &lt;html&gt; &lt;head&gt; &lt;title&gt;New Webpage&lt;/title&gt; &lt;/head&gt; &lt;body&gt; &lt;/body&gt; &lt;/html&gt;
</textarea>

<div id="readout"></div>
```

It works as it should: it outputs the HTML to the `#readout`. What goes wrong is when a user adds a `<style>` tag in the `head`. Then the style added there affects not only the HTML in the text input, but in the entire page.
How can I make the CSS affect only the user's input, and not the entire page?
Here is the [Problem Page](http://sarkelliancreed.comule.com/practice/html).

Comment: How does he add something to `<head>`? Your script puts everything in the `readout` DIV.

Comment: Look at the page. Try adding a style tag in the head and messing with the body's padding. It will affect the actual page's padding, not the readout.

Comment: The real solution is to do it like jsfiddle and codepen do: put the user's code into an iframe so it doesn't affect the main page.

Comment: You shouldn't have `<head>` inside a DIV. There can only be one `<head>` in a document, and it has to be outside the `<body>`

Comment: Another solution may be [Shadow DOM](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/shadowdom/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should really consider using a different approach to achieve this.

If you would really want to go with what you have so far you would have to replace a lot of stuff within the textarea value. Just to give you an idea, in the below snippet i am only replacing the `html` and `body` style declarations with the `id` (**#readout**) to apply the styles to the **#readout** `div` and not to the `body` of the page. It does work for the `body`, but what is with all the other possible declarations?

Sure i am a real noob when it comes to regex and i am sure this can be done a lot better, but all of this is not necessary.

```js
$("#tryit").keyup(function() {
    var style = $(this).val().match(/<style>(.*)<\/style>/);
    if (style !== null && style.length > 0) {
        var bodyReplace = style[1].replace(/(^|\s)(html)|(body)(\s|$)/ig, '#readout');
    }
  var input = $(this).val();
  $("#readout").html(input.replace(/<style>.*<\/style>/, '<style>'+bodyReplace+'</style>'));
});

$("#tryit").keyup();
```

```css
#readout {
  height: 400px;
  width: 48%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow: auto;
  float: right;
  clear: none;
  display: inline-block;
}
#tryit {
  height: 396px;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  clear: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: monospace;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea name="tryit" id="tryit" rows="10">&lt;!doctype html&gt; &lt;html&gt; &lt;head&gt; &lt;title&gt;New Webpage&lt;/title&gt;<style>body {background: black; color: red }</style> &lt;/head&gt; &lt;body&gt;<h1>Hello</h1> &lt;/body&gt; &lt;/html&gt;
</textarea>
<div id="readout"></div>
```

An other problem is that the `<doctype>`, `<html>`, `<head>` and `<body>` elements in your `textarea` do not really exist. Take a look at the source and you will find out that they are not there and they do not belong there. That being said i would go with a solution mentioned in a comment by *Barmar*, who suggested using an `iframe`.

It is actually not that hard to achieve. One quick and dirty way is to crate a `blob` from the textarea `value` and add that to the source attribute of an `iframe`. That would make it easy to even separate your HTML and CSS by having another textarea for the CSS and injecting it's `value` as a style-sheet into the head of the `iframe`. Since i can't use the `iframe` thing in the SO snippet tool because of sandbox security stuff check this

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/xoet6ph7/)

and i am sure you will get the idea.

Answer (score 2):

In your css make it to where it selects your div input with a specific id then select its child elements:

```
<style>    
#readout input{
     color: red;
}
</style>
```

**I added the style tag since you are putting the css directly in your html editor**.
The above css will only affect every input element in your div with the id of readout.

If you are looking for something different please say so

[Look at this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gr0q3cck/)

Comment: No, this is not what I want. Look at the page with the problem. If you add style in the textarea, it will affect the actual page, not the readout div

Comment: Any style that you putt in that editor should be wrapped in a **style** tag so it knows that its css and not text

Comment: yes, but style wrapped in a style tag affects the entire page, not the div with an id of readout

Comment: @code you're answering a different problem. The issue is when the user of the web page types `<style>...</style>` into the textarea.

Comment: How is this an issue I typed it on your page and it worked for me?

Comment: You can't force the user to enter selectors that begin with `#readout`.

Comment: If they're adding they're own classes how else do they add them without a css editor on the page? They wont know what the classes are....The only way for them to add style without creating theyre own class is to use the **style** attribute unless he has a css editor

Comment: You cant force them to but if they want classes with only **1** in-line editor....